# Why does multithreading my single-threaded simple echo server cause it to stop working?

Tags: java, multithreading

This single threaded echo server works fine.

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(1111)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket dataSocket = sc.accept();
                        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        dataSocket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                                dataSocket.getOutputStream());) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        out.println(line);
                        out.flush();
                        if (line.equals("Bye."))
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But why does this multi-threaded version not work? It simply passes input and output streams to construct a TestServer1 thread and start it. Nothing special. But somehow when a client connects to this server, A `"Stream close"` exception is thrown in `run()` and `"error in run"` is printed.

```
public class TestServer1 extends Thread{
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    public TestServer1(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out){
        this.in=in;
        this.out=out;       
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        String line;
        try{
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            out.println(line);
            out.flush();
            if (line.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("error in run");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(1111)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket dataSocket = sc.accept();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        dataSocket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                                dataSocket.getOutputStream());) {
                    TestServer1 ts1=new TestServer1(in, out);
                    ts1.start();        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
error in run
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:115)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:310)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at server.TestServer1.run(TestServer1.java:22)
```

Comment: Please add a full stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I think whats happening is that you are closing the outputstream implicitly with the 'Try With Resources' before you're done writing to it in your run method

Comment: @Amir Thanks, you're right. The stream was closed after the main thread goes out of the try block. And your version blow works.

Answer (score 1):

> Java 7: Try with resources
>
> With Java 7, you can create one or more “resources” in the try
>   statement. A “resources” is something that implements the
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable interface. This resource would be
>   automatically closed and the end of the try block.

- See more at: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2011/03/java-7-try-with-auto-closable-resources/#sthash.cnvRzGIZ.dpuf

From javadocs:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

}

> In this example, the resource declared in the try-with-resources statement is a BufferedReader. The declaration statement appears within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class BufferedReader, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method BufferedReader).

Link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

So probably this can be reason , your streams are closed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Yes, the closed streams were the cause of the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

the try () is the reason. the stream will be closed after the try (.....) block.
Please test this code:

```
 while (true) {
    try { 
        Socket dataSocket = sc.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            dataSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
            dataSocket.getOutputStream());
        TestServer1 ts1 = new TestServer1 (in, out);
        ts1.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

P.S: You need to close the stream in the thread run() method.

Comment: You were right. the try-block closed the streams. Your version should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version out below - its untested.  But as I said in my comment, I believe you are closing the output stream prematurely in your TryWithResources

```
public class TestServer1 extends Thread{
    Socket connection;

    public TestServer1(Socket connection){
        this.connection = connection;       
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());) {

            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    out.println(line);
                    out.flush();
                    if (line.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.print("error in run");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(1111)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket dataSocket = sc.accept()) {
                    TestServer1 ts1=new TestServer1(dataSocket);
                    ts1.start();        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from @Amir, @LFF and @Abhijeet, I put together the following version, and it works. The main take aways is: "Socket dataSocket = sc.accept()" should not be put into "try()" as a resource; otherwise, the main thread will close it. It should be closed by the child thread in "run()".

Thank you all for your help.

```
public class ThreadedServer extends Thread {
    private Socket dataSocket;

    public ThreadedServer(Socket dataSocket) throws IOException {
        this.dataSocket = dataSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                dataSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(dataSocket.getOutputStream());) {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                out.println(line);
                out.flush();
                if (line.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                dataSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(1111)) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket dataSocket = sc.accept();
                    ThreadedServer ts = new ThreadedServer(dataSocket);
                    ts.start();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```